# ENOENT while creating a UNIX socket in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, unix

I'm trying to create a socket in Ruby using

```
require "socket"
w = UNIXSocket.new("socket")
```

and I keep running into

```
No such file or directory - socket (Errno::ENOENT)
```

This looks completely backwards to me, because `new()` is *supposed* to create that missing file. What am I missing?

Comment: permission problem? Or in a directory that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @Chuck Vose: Definitely neither of those...that's why it's so perplexing.

Comment: Oh, haha. UnixSocket.new is an alias for open.

Comment: Still trying to find an example of how to do it right. I'm seeing the same problem on my system

Comment: Dunno, maybe we're both cracked. I can't find examples that are more complicated than this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is super old. Please don't try to use it verbatim anymore.

http://blog.antarestrader.com/posts/153

```
#!/ruby
file = 'path/to/my/socket'
File.unlink if File.exists(file) && File.socket?(file)
server = UNIXServer.new(file)
# return a UNIXSocket once a connection is made 
socket = server.accept
# socket is now ready to communicate.
```

UnixServer makes the socket, UnixSocket only connects to an existing socket.

Comment: Wow, thank you. It's crazy that this information isn't more easily accessible. Every example I found showed new as creating a new socket.

Comment: This code does not work on Ruby 2.0.0 for me. First: File.unlink takes a path. Second, I get the same no such file or directory error as the OP.

Comment: This should probably be "File.unlink(file)" in the code

Comment: What is the modern way to do this?